# How to create multiple counters

Tags: jquery, counter

I found the original posted question about a simple jquery counter at [Javascript, increment a counter on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328717/simple-jquery-counter-issue).  I have borrowed the final solution for the script, and it works very easily, just like in the demo through JSFIDDLE.  However, I am running into a slight problem.  I need three individual counters, that work separately from one another.  Can someone please help me work with this existing script function, to create the three multiple counters I need?  Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you attempted to find a solution on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/H63As/30/

//wrote the code down here just in case...

html

```
<div>
    <div id="counter1">0</div>
    <div id="counter2">0</div>
    <div id="counter3">0</div>
    <button class="add" type="button" val="1">Add</button>
    <button class="add" type="button" val="2">Add</button>
    <button class="add" type="button" val="3">Add</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(function () {
          $(".add").on("click", function () {
              $("#counter" + $(this).attr("val")).text(Number($("#counter" + $(this).attr("val")).text()) + 1);
          });

      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.  @Vivin Paliath, I did try to work with the script, but working with scripts is one of my weak areas; which is why I posted my question in the first place.  I am very sorry that you feel that this was not a worthy question.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your kindness and for taking the time to help me.

Comment: You're welcome. Please click the up arrow so that people can see this question has been resolved. :)

Comment: I am afraid that I am unable to do so.  I keep getting an error message that I have to have a reputation of 15.